# VLC loses playback location when streaming to Chromecast

Tags: vlc-media-player, video-playback

I'm using VLC to stream local videos to Chromecast, which works great except for a couple things:

- If I pause for more than a few seconds, hitting play again appears to take awhile to reconnect and start playing again; seems like it's losing connection.
- When this happens, the location is often lost and it goes backward 20-80 seconds in time, if not more. This does not occur when playing videos on my own screen.

Comment: Pretty annoying but you'll have to live with it. Or find a better solition.

Comment: Are you saying it's a permanent thing, and there will be no bug fix? If so, what are you basing this on?